# Eclipse: Serial terminal: Treat /n as /n/r

Tags: eclipse, terminal, serial-port, linefeed, truestudio

I am using Eclipse variant called Atollic TrueSTUDIO version 9.2.0 for the STM32 platform.

When I do `printf("Hello World\n");` from the microcontroller, is it possible to configure the Eclipse terminal to treat the `\n` as a newline? Without the carriage return, Eclipse does not return the cursor to the start of the line.

Is it possible to do this? I tried the following: Window->Preferences->General->Workspace, and on this window selected "New text file line delimiter: Unix", but this did not work for me.

Below image illustrates the problem.
[image: Eclipse not treating \n as line feed carriage return]

Answer (score 0):

two options:

1. `printf("Hello World\r\n");`
2. Use another program for example realterm which allow you to append `\r` to every `\n`
3. `#define myprintf(fmt, ...) {printf(fmt, ___VA_ARG__); printf("\r");}`

But I do not really understand

Answer (score 0):

I'd really like to use the internal terminal to display stuff, but this is still a problem. osstreams terminated with std::endl; lead to this weird indentation. No fix to this yet? I have not found a way to have implicit carriaghe return with line feed in the eclipse settings for the terminal

Comment: I'm assuming that you've defined the `__io_putchar` method in order to direct `printf` (or `std::cout`) to the UART - in which case, you could add a condition in `__io_putchar` that if we're called with `\n`, then also call `__io_putchar('\r')`.

something like

`extern "C" int __io_putchar(int ch)`
`{`
`    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, 0xFFFF);`
``
`    if (ch = '\n')`
`        __io_putchar('\r');`
``
`    return ch;`
`}`

(untested)

Comment: It does indeed print to a Serial interface. I solved the problem for now by modifying our stream buffer sync function (which was overriden to add a preamble to custom osstreams) to have an option to add an optional "\r" at the beginning. Problem is that when I run this in a regular program which does print to std::cout directly, it will recognize \r\n as two line breaks.